# Change Kubernetes nginx-ingress-controller ports

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I installed Minikube v1.3.1 on my RedHat EC2 instance for some tests.

***Since the ports that the nginx-ingress-controller uses by default are already in use, I am trying to change them in the deployment but without result. Could please somebody advise how to do it?***

**How do I know that the port are already in Use?**

When I listed the system pods using the command `kubectl -n kube-system get deployment | grep nginx`, I get:

> nginx-ingress-controller   0/1     1            0           9d

meaning that my container is not up. When I describe it using the command `kubectl -n kube-system describe pod nginx-ingress-controller-xxxxx` I get:

> Type     Reason                  Age                        From
>   Message   ----     ------                  ----
>   ----               -------   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  42m (x163507 over 2d1h)    kubelet, minikube  (combined from similar
>   events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   failed to start sandbox container for pod
>   "nginx-ingress-controller-xxxx": Error response from daemon: driver
>   failed programming external connectivity on endpoint
>   k8s_POD_nginx-ingress-controller-xxxx_kube-system_...: Error starting
>   userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

Then I check the processes using those ports and I kill them. That free them up and the ingress-controller pod gets deployed correctly.

What did I try to change the nginx-ingress-controller port?

```
kubectl -n kube-system get deployment | grep nginx

> NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
> nginx-ingress-controller   0/1     1            0           9d

kubectl -n kube-system edit deployment nginx-ingress-controller
```

The relevant part of my deployment looks like this:

```
name: nginx-ingress-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 81
          hostPort: 81
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 444
          hostPort: 444
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 18080
          hostPort: 18080
          protocol: TCP
```

Then I remove the subsections with port 443 and 80, but when I rollout the changes, **they get added again**.

Now my services are not reachable anymore through ingress.

Comment: Hello AR1,
Can you please share the complete NGINX deployment YAML? It would be helpful to completely understand the scenario. On the other hand, are you using the K8s documentation[1] or other guide?

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for your answer. I didn't post the full YAML because of its length. The part that I posted is the only difference with the default one. I followed the documentation already and ingress is working fine unless I change the NGINX port as specified in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that **minikube** ships with [**addon-manager**](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager), which role is to keep an eye on specific addon template files (default location: `/etc/kubernetes/addons/`) and do one of two specific actions based on the label's value of managed resource:

> addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode

1. `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile`

> Will be periodically reconciled. Direct manipulation to these addons
> through apiserver is discouraged because addon-manager will bring
> them back to the original state. In particular

2. `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=KeepOnly`

> Will be checked for existence only. Users can edit these addons as
> they want.

So to keep your customized version of default Ingress service listening ports, please change first the [Ingress deployment template configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/ff0e25ada888cf1bd7b262857ce96531c1231e69/deploy/addons/ingress/ingress-dp.yaml.tmpl#L281) to `KeepOnly` on minikube VM.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `minikube` bootstraps Nginx [Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) as the separate addon, thus as per design you might have to enable it in order to propagate the particular *Ingress Controller's* resources within `minikube` cluster.

Once you enabled some specific `minikube` [Addon](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/contributing/addons/), [Addon-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager/README.md) creates template files for each component by placing them into `/etc/kubernetes/addons/` folder on the host machine, and then spin up each manifest file, creating corresponded K8s resources; furthermore *Addon-manager* continuously inspects the actual state for all addon resources synchronizing *K8s* target resources (service, deployment, etc.) according to the template data.

Therefore, you can consider modifying *Ingress* addon template data throughout `ingress-*.yaml` files under `/etc/kubernetes/addons/` directory, propagating the desired values into the target k8s objects; it may takes some until K8s engine reflects the changes and re-spawns the relative [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) based resources.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. That's the generic process but it doesn't answer the question. Ingress has been enabled already and it's working fine unless I try to change port to the NGINX as specified in the question.

Comment: I've just explained how you can change the default Nginx Ingress controller's ports in `minikube` and why the values are turned to default ones after you rolled out customized ports. At least you can check logs from Ingress controller Pod to figure out whether initials requests are reaching the destination app services or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have to modify the Ingress which refer to the service you're trying to expose on custom port.

This can be done with custom annotation. Here is an example for your port 444:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/listen-ports-ssl: "444"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - host.org
    secretName: my-host-tls-cert
  rules:
  - host: host.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 444
```